# Cannot get a series highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to make a chart with multiple series (19). I want each series to have multiple points so it did that to create the first series with the first set of data and then just add points to each series:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          defaultSeriesType: 'line',
          events: {
            load: function() {
              var rawArray = <%- dataArray %>;
              var array = {};
              var chart = this;
              for (var i = 0; i < rawArray.length; i++) {
                var entry = rawArray[i];
                var str = entry.timestamp.toString();
                var time = str.slice(0, -3);
                var array = [
                  [parseInt(time), entry.price]
                ];
                if (i < 18) {
                  $('#container').highcharts().addSeries({
                    name: entry.name,
                    id: entry.id,
                    data: array
                  });
                } else {
                  $('#container').highcharts().series[entry.id].addPoint(array, false, true);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Title'
        },
        xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          tickPixelInterval: 150
        },
        yAxis: {
          minPadding: 0.2,
          maxPadding: 0.2,
          title: {
            text: 'Value',
            margin: 80
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

So the first 19 series add just fine but then there's this message in my console: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addPoint' of undefined' reffering to the `$('#container').highcharts().series[entry.id].addPoint(array, false, true);`

I'd like to know if you guys have a solution for me, it'd be really appreciated!

Comment: Hello, you can make a jsFiddle example?

Comment: Instead of construction $('#container').highcharts().series[entry.id] you should use [get()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.get) function.

Comment: @Cuchu Of course! Here's the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/99x477sb/4/

Comment: @SebastianBochan I've tried that but it doesn't work either :c

Comment: Because your series require to have unique ID (i.e like your name). So add the parameter and will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/99x477sb/5/

```
 for (var i = 0; i < rawArray.length; i++) {
            var entry = rawArray[i];
            var id = entry.id;
            var str = entry.timestamp.toString();
            var time = str.slice(0, -3);
            var array = [[parseInt(time), entry.price]];
            var array_to_point = [parseInt(time), entry.price];
            console.log(array);
            if (i < 18) {
              $('#container').highcharts().addSeries({
                name: entry.name,
                id: entry.id,
                data: array
              });
            } else {
            $.each(this.series, function(i, v){
                serieId = chart.series[i].options.id;
              if(serieId == id) {
                chart.series[i].addPoint(array_to_point,false);
              }

                //chart.series[i].addPoint(series[serieId], false);
                });
            //console.log(this.series);
             //$('#container').highcharts().series[id].addPoint(array, false, true);
              //$('#container').highcharts().get(entry.name).addPoint(array, false, true);

            }
          }
          this.redraw(true);
```

My english is more basic but i try to explicate.
When you set id: entry.id, the id to serie is defined in chart.series[i].options.id  the i isn't id because is the index into the series graph.

```
var array = [[parseInt(time), entry.price]];
var array_to_point = [parseInt(time), entry.price];
```

in first run array define data serie = array(points)  where points = array(time, value).. ok? then in addpoint, modified for add point to data arra_to_point = [time,value]..

In the finish, redraw graph..

I have done many jobs with Highcharts and always have to be looking at the contents of the elements to take pulse

Comment: Is good practice, create the graph and series empty and then create function when add all points to series.

Comment: Try and comment! @Hiro